# How is signing a hash different from signing a message?

Tags: web3.py, signature, hash, verify

I've got an Arduino microcontroller (ATmega328P) where I can use the following code  (borrowed from [here](https://github.com/firefly/wallet)) snippet to sign an arbitrary message . First, I take the `keccak256` hash of the message, and the code produces a hash that is successfully verified using Etherscan's "[Verify Message](https://etherscan.io/verifiedSignatures#)" tool. The message below is `1234`

```
static const uint8_t nprivateKey[] = {
0x02,0x86,0xeb,0xe8,0x02,0xee,0x88,0x2c,
0x16,0x3b,0xee,0x41,0xbd,0x6b,0xbd,0x93,
0x1b,0xf1,0x7a,0x8a,0x2d,0xcf,0xa7,0x28,
0xf5,0xb5,0x2d,0x47,0xd0,0x80,0x6d,0x0a};

  // keccak256 of "1234": 
  0x387a8233c96e1fc0ad5e284353276177af2186e7afa85296f106336e376669f7
  uint8_t hash[32] = {
  0x38, 0x7a, 0x82, 0x33, 0xc9, 0x6e, 0x1f, 0xc0,
  0xad, 0x5e, 0x28, 0x43, 0x53, 0x27, 0x61, 0x77,
  0xaf, 0x21, 0x86, 0xe7, 0xaf, 0xa8, 0x52, 0x96,
  0xf1, 0x06, 0x33, 0x6e, 0x37, 0x66, 0x69, 0xf7
};
  
uECC_sign(nprivateKey, hash, 32, signature, uECC_secp256k1());
signed_tx = String(convertBytesKeyToHexKey(signature, 65));
```

Sometimes we need to sign transaction hashes, as when interacting with a Gnosis safe. The code above produces a verifiable signature for `1234`, but when I take the `keccak256` hash of a transaction hash, the signature produced is invalid. I've also tried using the 65-byte transaction hash directly, skipping the `keccak256` step, but the resulting signature is also invalid.

When I use python to sign the same transaction hash, however, the signature is valid:

```
from eth_account import Account
from hexbytes import  HexBytes
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3()
contract_transaction_hash = HexBytes('0x610f9dee9a3d29d00a8af5096ce777f413b5975de0f6deff60b0e15863d7e0fd0f010604e2608b4fb355e551bcf545352eb50dfd1493126bc1e30a9c3094195b64')
account = Account.from_key('0x0286ebe802ee882c163bee41bd6bbd931bf17a8a2dcfa728f5b52d47d0806d0a')
signature = account.signHash(contract_transaction_hash)
print(signature.signature.hex()) #this signature is valid
```

So, for the microcontroller, in the case of a message like `1234`, taking the `keccak256` hash and signing produces a valid signature, but in the case of signing a transaction hash, the signature is invalid. If I use python to sign the transaction hash, however, the signature is valid.

This means that there is some difference between what the python code is doing to sign and what the C code of the microcontroller is doing to sign.

Is there a fundamental difference between signing an arbitrary message and signing a transaction hash? Does `signHash` first take the `keccak256` hash of the message before signing?

How does the `eth_account` `signHash` function work under the hood, and how is it different from what the `ethers` `uECC_sign` function is doing?

Comment: I don't know any of the libraries you are using but have you tried to create a hex buffer from the 65-byte transaction hash rather than using keccak256.

Comment: @ruby_newbie yes I think I tried using hash directly with `uint8_t hash[65]` but no dice. I will double check though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For signing Gnosis safe transaction hashes, I had to add `1c` to the end of `uECC_sign` output to produce a valid signature

For signing a message (to verify a signature), I had to add `1b` to the end of `uECC_sign` output to produce a valid signature

I tried appending those because of a question [here](https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc/issues/201). To my surprise, it worked.

Also I had to change the `size` parameter when calling `convertBytesKeyToHexKey` to `64`.

Now it works

So at least in this case, the answer to the question seems to be: Add "1c" when signing a tx hash and "1b" when signing a message hash. When signing a tx hash, no need to take `keccak256` of the hash before signing.

```
//same nprivateKey and hash values as above

uint8_t signature[64];
uECC_sign(nprivateKey, hash, 32, signature, uECC_secp256k1());

//for message signature (verifying signature) add 1b to the end of the 
signature

signed_tx = "0x" + String(convertBytesKeyToHexKey(signature, 64)) + "1b";

/*
//for signing Gnosis tx hash, add 1c to the end of the signature
gnosis_signed_tx = "0x" + String(convertBytesKeyToHexKey(signature, 64)) + "1c";
*/
```